advanced multi conditional list comprehension
I am new to Python and would like to assign a value based on mathematical operations, eg "right" if >, "left" if <, "equal" if ==, within a list comprehension.
I have tried the below, but it throws an error. Can multiple conditions be specified in a single list comprehension in this way, where each "elif" generates a different output, or will I need to use a loop?
Fully reproduceable example:
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris

bunch = load_iris(as_frame=True)
df = bunch.data.reset_index().rename(columns={"index": "id"}).merge(bunch.target.reset_index().rename(columns={"index": "id"})).drop(["id"], axis=1)

# question is in last row, "skew"
datasummary_dct = {
   "50%": [df[col].median().round(2) if any(t in str(df[col].dtype) for t in ("float", "int", "time")) else " " for col in df.columns],
   "mean": [df[col].mean().round(2) if any(t in str(df[col].dtype) for t in ("float", "int", "time")) else " " for col in df.columns],
   "skew": ["left" if df[col].median() > df[col].mean() else "right" if df[col].median() < df[col].mean() else "equal" if df[col].median()==df[col].mean() if any(t in str(df[col].dtype) for t in ("float", "int", "time")) else " " for col in df.columns],
}

again I am still fairly new to programming; apologies if I do not immediately understand the solution. any guidance is appreciated!

You have to put the condition after the main loop. [df[col].median().round(2) for col in df.columns if any(t in str(df[col].dtype) for t in ("float", "int", "time"))]

@OysterShucker but where would the else if statements go in that example?

Instead of the complex nested if, you can use np.select for this which is much more readable:
datasummary_dct = {
    "skew": [
        np.select(
            [df[col].median() > df[col].mean(), df[col].median() < df[col].mean()],
            ["right", "left"],
            "equal",
        )
        if any(t in str(df[col].dtype) for t in ("float", "int", "time"))
        else " "
        for col in df.columns
    ],
}

print(pd.DataFrame(datasummary_dct))

Output:
    skew
0   left
1   left
2  right
3  right
4  equal


You can make life a bit easier by first selecting the columns for which your aggregations make sense. Also, your list comprehension for 'skew' is recalculating values already retrieved; it makes sense to utilize those.
Minimal Reproducible Example
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0) # for reproducibility
N = 5

data = {'float': np.random.rand(N),
        'int': np.random.randint(0, 10, size=N),
        'datetime': pd.date_range('1900-01-01', periods=N),
        'timedelta': pd.timedelta_range(start='1 day', periods=N),
        'str': np.random.choice([*'ABC'], size=N)}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df

      float  int   datetime timedelta str
0  0.548814    5 1900-01-01    1 days   A
1  0.715189    2 1900-01-02    2 days   A
2  0.602763    4 1900-01-03    3 days   A
3  0.544883    7 1900-01-04    4 days   C
4  0.423655    6 1900-01-05    5 days   B

Solution
def skew(df):
    condlist = [df['median'] > df['mean'],
                df['median'] < df['mean']]
    choicelist = ['left', 'right']
    return np.select(condlist, choicelist, default='equal')

dtypes = ['number', 'datetime', 'timedelta']

out = (df.select_dtypes(include=dtypes)
       .agg(['median', 'mean'])
       .T
       .pipe(lambda x: x.assign(skew=skew))
       .reindex(df.columns, fill_value='N/A')
       .rename(columns={'median': '50%'})
       )

Output:
                           50%                 mean   skew
float                 0.548814             0.567061  right
int                        5.0                  4.8   left
datetime   1900-01-03 00:00:00  1900-01-03 00:00:00  equal
timedelta      3 days 00:00:00      3 days 00:00:00  equal
str                        N/A                  N/A    N/A

Explanation / Intermediates

Use df.select_dtypes to get the subset for which your aggregations make sense, and use df.agg to get 'median' and 'mean'.

df.select_dtypes(include=dtypes).agg(['median', 'mean'])

           float  int   datetime timedelta
median  0.548814  5.0 1900-01-03    3 days
mean    0.567061  4.8 1900-01-03    3 days


Transpose the result (df.T) and use df.pipe to chain the operation needed to get the values for 'skew'. For this we use np.select, adding the values as a new column with df.assign.

(df.select_dtypes(include=dtypes)
 .agg(['median', 'mean'])
 .T
 .pipe(lambda x: x.assign(skew=skew))
 )

                        median                 mean   skew
float                 0.548814             0.567061  right
int                        5.0                  4.8   left
datetime   1900-01-03 00:00:00  1900-01-03 00:00:00  equal
timedelta      3 days 00:00:00      3 days 00:00:00  equal


Now, we can use df.reindex to add back the filtered-out columns (i.e., 'str').
Finally, use df.rename to rename column 'median' to '50%'.


Fix OP's method
To make the original attempt work, it will be easier to start with the value you need when 'median' and 'mean' make no sense. The logic being: return "N/A" if the dtype is not included (not any(...)), else do magic to return 'left, right, equal (default)`.
"N/A" if not any(t in str(df[col].dtype) for t in dtypes) else 'comparisons'

I've used 'N/A' for visibility, but this is OP's ' '. The key thing to realize is that such a list comprehension needs to end with a logical default else. In full:
dtypes = ['float', 'int', 'time']
datasummary_dct = {
   "50%": [df[col].median() if any(t in str(df[col].dtype) for t in dtypes) 
           else "N/A" for col in df.columns],
   "mean": [df[col].mean() if any(t in str(df[col].dtype) for t in dtypes) 
            else "N/A" for col in df.columns],
    "skew": [
        "N/A" if not any(t in str(df[col].dtype) for t in dtypes)
        else "left" if df[col].median() > df[col].mean()
        else "right" if df[col].median() < df[col].mean() 
        else "equal" for col in df.columns],
}

out2 = pd.DataFrame(datasummary_dct, index=df.columns)

Same output:
out2.equals(out)
# True


The "N/A" solution does not work, as I am creating a sparse matrix to summarize data. I will review your other solutions to see if they work within the same function (or if they require a more ~complex~ application). Thanks for your help !!

@plotmaster473: "[it] does not work". What part of it doesn't work / how does it not work? Does it lead to wrong values / does it cause an error? If you apply both my solution and the suggested fix of your original df, you should get the same output with both methods. That being the case, perhaps you can show us how your actual df differs from the example provided?

for this use case, leaving blank is more accurate than np.nan or otherwise falsey values, as the table is meant to communicate clean information summary ( frankly I don't really see the need to break that part of the problem statement down, in any case). Regardless, thank you for your solution, it's very good! At the risk of overcomplicating things I check above as the selected answer.

I used "N/A" only for visibility purposes in the prints; just change it back to " ", if that is what you want/need (which is not a blank, but a single whitespace). Incidentally, I don't understand what you mean to say here: "I don't really see the need to break that part of the problem statement down". But sure, the other solution also works to get 'skew'.

Just that it’s inefficient if I am trying to be as concise as possible
